# Mui Snackbar Close Icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a notification component that renders `mui snackbar` with `alert`. I want to show 3 notifications at a the same time under eachother. The problem is that when i try to close the second notification with clicking on the `Close` icon, it closes both (first and second). I mean each time it closes itself and the above one. What is the problem here?

```
type Props = {
  notifications: NotificationState[];
  removeNotification: (id: number) => void;
};

export function Notification({ notifications, removeNotification }: Props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<{ [key: number]: boolean }>({});

  const handleClose = (id: number) => () => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => ({
      ...prevOpen,
      [id]: false,
    }));
    removeNotification(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatedOpenMap: { [key: number]: boolean } = {};
    notifications.forEach((notification) => {
      updatedOpenMap[notification.id] = true;
    });
    setOpen(updatedOpenMap);
  }, [notifications]);

  return (
    <>
      {notifications.map((notification, index) => (
        <Snackbar
          key={notification.id}
          open={open[notification.id]}
          autoHideDuration={5000}
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
          onClose={handleClose(notification.id)}
          style={{ marginTop: `${index * 60}px` }}
        >
          <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
            <Alert severity={notification.type} onClose={handleClose(notification.id)}>
              {notification.message}
            </Alert>
          </div>
        </Snackbar>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
export default Notification;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues, first of all you're calling `handleClose` incorrectly, secondly the `marginTop` of Alert div parent is making interruption, try to remove it, this is the final code which works as you might expect:

```
type Props = {
  notifications: NotificationState[];
  removeNotification: (id: number) => void;
};

export function Notification({ notifications, removeNotification }: Props) {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState<{ [key: number]: boolean }>({});

  const handleClose = (id: number) => () => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => ({
      ...prevOpen,
      [id]: false
    }));
    removeNotification(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatedOpenMap: { [key: number]: boolean } = {};
    notifications.forEach((notification) => {
      updatedOpenMap[notification.id] = true;
    });
    setOpen(updatedOpenMap);
  }, [notifications]);

  return (
    <>
      {notifications.map((notification, index) => (
        <Snackbar
          key={notification.id}
          open={open[notification.id]}
          autoHideDuration={5000}
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
          onClose={() => handleClose(notification.id)}
          style={{ marginTop: `${index * 60}px` }}
        >
          <Alert severity={notification.type as any} onClose={handleClose(notification.id)}>
            {notification.message}
          </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Notification;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are directly calling onClose={handleClose(notification.id)} which is most probably causing issue,
do it like
onClose{()=>handleClose(notification.id)}

Comment: i did that, now when i click on Close button nothing happened